# how to convert a script using pipelines to named pipes

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, fifo, named-pipe

I have a bash script that is using anonymous pipes to achieve:

- grabbing video from dv capture device
- writing to a file (using tee)
- piping it to ffmpeg2theora (converting to ogv/theora video)
- writing to a file (using tee)
- piping it to oggfwd in order to send it to icecast streaming server

How could I achieve that using named pipes (fifos), so that I could have separate processes that I could separately control?

I was using this script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 while (true); 
 do
    dvgrab --format dv1 - | \
    tee /filename_`date +%y%m%d_%H%M%S`.dv | \
    ffmpeg2theora.linux -f dv -x 382 -y 288 -v 3 --speedlevel 2 --no-skeleton -o /dev/stdout - | \
    tee /filename_`date +%y%m%d_%H%M%S`_stream_382x288.ogv | \
    oggfwd icecastserver.com 8000 password /mountpoint.ogv
done
```

One of the reasons I'm asking this is that I need to have clean dv files and ogv files on disk regardless if the network is up and icecast streaming server reachable.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do this with ordinary files if your don't need any concurrency at all. The principle for named pipes is the same

Change

```
foo | \
bar | \
baz
```

To

```
foo > foo.out
bar < foo.out > bar.out
baz < bar.out
```

If the *.out are named pipes then I suspect the programs writing to them may get blocked waiting for their output buffers to be drained.